# React native keeps requesting react-native-cli to be installed globally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Here are the steps I did to set up my project:

```
$ git clone ssh:<project>
$ cd <project>
$ nvm install 5.0
$ nvm use 5.0
```

I then check my node version and it appears to be correct: `v5.0.0`.

```
$ npm install
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
```

This all seems to go according to plan, and locally, it gives me a tree with all the correct dependencies.

When I do `npm list --depth=0 -g`, I get expected results.

```
├── npm@3.3.6
└── react-native-cli@1.0.0
```

So I try to run the `npm start` script, which is `react-native start`. However, whenever I try to run it, I get the following basic error:

```
Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of, down to uninstalling node and nvm completely and starting from scratch.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This upcoming error message is not very helpful. Besides your npm installation issue I found also an [npm start doesn't work after upgrade to 0.15.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4341) bugfixing issue with the same error message.

First of all you should check the symbolic link shown after npm install:

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
   /usr/local/bin/react-native -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

Check if the linked file exists:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

If not, check your [npm path settings](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) with

```
npm config list
```

or directly in ~/.npmrc

In my case I had a wrong prefix in ~/.npmrc, which I've deleted completely. As the npm ERR! message shows after another npm install -g react-native-cli, it came up with:

```
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/react-native: ../lib/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/wrong-react-native.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/react-native
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Look at the indicated 'wrong-react-native.js' filename at the end.

**Delete that link**, do a npm update and try npm install -g react-native-cli again.

Worked on MacOS X. npm installed with homebrew